# MVC LINQ Test repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am creating a test repository for dependency injection and i have my test method below.

```
private List<object> records;

public IList<T> GetFiltered<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> action = null) where T : class
{
    return ((List<T>)records).Where(action).ToList();
}
```

I essentially want to return a filtered list of records where the "action" condition is true.

I get the error below

> Error 2   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Please help.

Comment: i get `Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' `

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `IEnumerable<T>` version of [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) which expects `Func<T, bool>` not `IQueryable<T>` which takes an `Expression` e.g.

```
public IList<T> GetFiltered<T>(Func<T, bool> action = null) where T : class
{
    return ((List<T>)records).Where(action).ToList();
}
```

Also, `List<object>` can't be cast to `List<T>` my advice would be to make the outer class generic as well i.e.

```
public class MyContainer<T>
{
    private List<T> records;

    public IList<T> GetFiltered(Func<T, bool> action = null) where T : class
    {
        return records.Where(action).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you can not just convert `List` of `object` to generic type
 you should do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965766/casting-listobject-to-listt-at-runtime) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933434/how-to-cast-listobject-to-listsomethingelse)